# Passing objects from web3 to smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, solidity-0.8.x

I have a contract in which there is a function which has 16 arguments which is giving me `stack too deep` error. So I am thinking of passing a javascript object using web3 to the smart contract which I will destructure in the method. So here I have two questions:

1. How to pass a javascript object using web3 to a smart contract?
2. How to destructure the object in a smart contract with each field having its respective values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use solidity structs.

```
struct MyStruct {
   uint256 number1;
   address address1;
   // ...
}

contract MyContract {
    function foo(MyStruct memory data) public {
        uint256 num1 = data.number1;
        address addr1 = data.address1;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Using web3js, you should be able to call the function like this:

```js
contract.foo({number1: 123, address1: '0x...'}).send()
```